# Semi-major axis , specific mechanical energy, its period and velocity at Apogee and Perigee and what the difference is

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Hi im needing some help with two questions could you please show the formula and the way its solved?Thanks
PS:Could you also explain what the difference of velocity and apogee and perigee?

1.)A satellite’s orbit is at a 45 degree inclination. It has a perigee altitude of 400 kilometers and an apogee altitude 2000 kilometers. It has an angular momentum of 54,653.38 km2/sec. What are its semi-major axis and its specific mechanical energy, its period and velocity at Apogee and Perigee?

2.)A satellite’s orbit has a period of  55.555 hours, and a semilatus rectum of 72,254.4 km. What is the orbit’s eccentricity?

Comment: Google "vis viva equation". It will get you most of your answers.

Comment: Hi Eric and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).